# Scheme macro expansion shows variable is unbound

Tags: macros, scheme

I am writing a simple lisp interpreter as I read Lisp in Small Pieces, but I am stuck on this error for over 2 hours now. I *am* defining a local `genv` variable but still I get this error. There must be some macro expansion thing I can't understand, I have checked the expansion using a quote, and it seems to be OK. Please if someone can shed some light it would be great. (The code works with r5rs language and guile scheme)

```
;; Macro to print it's given arguments line by line and end with a ------
(define-syntax println
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ expr expr* ...) (begin (display expr)
                               (newline)
                               (println expr* ...)))
    ((_ expr) (begin (display expr) (newline)))
    ((_) (display "--------\n"))))

(define (evaluate expr env)
  (begin (println "Evaluating" expr)
  (if (not (pair? expr))
      (cond ((symbol? expr) (lookup env expr))
            ((or (number? expr) (string? expr) (char? expr) (boolean? expr) (vector? expr)) expr)
            (else (error "Cannot evaluate" expr)))

      ;; not atom
      (case (car expr)
        ((quote) (cadr expr))

        ;; (define name expr)
        ((define) (update (cadr expr) (caddr expr) env))

        ((if) (if (evaluate (cadr expr) env)
                  (evaluate (caddr expr) env)
                  (evaluate (cadddr expr) env)))

        ((begin) (eprogn (cdr expr) env))

        ((set!) (update (cadr expr) (evaluate (caddr expr) env) env))

        ((lambda) (make-function (cadr expr) (cddr expr) env))

        (else (invoke (evaluate (car expr) env)
                      (evlis (cdr expr) env)))))))

;; Evaluates all the expressions (exprs) in the given environment (env)
(define (eprogn exprs env)
  (if (pair? exprs)

      ;; False when exprs contains just one item
      (if (pair? (cdr exprs))

          (begin (evaluate (car exprs) env)
                 (eprogn (cdr exprs) env))

          (evaluate (car exprs) env))

      '()))


(define (evlis exprs env)
  (if (pair? exprs)
      (cons (evaluate (car exprs) env)
            (evlis (cdr exprs) env))
      '()))

;; Makes a new applicable function, that closes the environment (env)
(define (make-function vars body env)
  (lambda (vals)
    (eprogn body (extend-environment env vars vals))))


(define (invoke fn args)
  (if (procedure? fn)
      (fn args)
      (error "Not a function" fn)))

;; Environment suite

;; Helper macros for working with an environment vector

;; Returns the parent environment of (env)
(define-syntax parent-env-of
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((parent-env-of env) (vector-ref env 0))))

;; Returns the bind-map of (env)
(define-syntax bind-map-of
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((bind-map-of env) (vector-ref env 1))))

;; Sets the parent environment of (env)
(define-syntax set-parent-env!
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((set-parent-env! env parent-env) (vector-set! env 0 parent-env))))

;; Sets the bind-map of (env)
(define-syntax set-bind-map!
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((set-bind-map! env bind-map) (vector-set! env 1 bind-map))))

;; Makes a new environment with the parent env set to (parent-env)
(define (make-new-environment parent-env)
  (let ((new-env (vector #f #f)))
    (begin
      (set-parent-env! new-env parent-env)
      (set-bind-map! new-env '())
      new-env)))

;; Searches for the value of (sym) in (env), raises
;; error if it can't find
(define (lookup env sym)
  (if (null? env)
      (error "Unbound name" sym)
      (let ((val (assoc sym (bind-map-of env))))
        (if (equal? val #f) (lookup (parent-env-of env) sym) (cdr val)))))

;; Create the binding update the (sym)'s value to (value) in the given (env)
(define (update sym value env)
  (begin (println "Called update with env: " env "sym: " sym "value: " value)
         (define new-bind-map (assoc-set! (bind-map-of env) sym value))
         (set-bind-map! env new-bind-map)))

;; Extends an (env) by creating a new environment and setting the
;; bindings specified by the list of symbols (vars) and the
;; list of values (vals)
(define (extend-environment vars vals env)
  (define new-env (make-new-environment env))
  (update-all vars vals env))

;; Helper function
(define (update-all vars vals env)
  (cond ((pair? vars) (if (not (pair? vals))
                          (error "More symbols than values to bind with")
                          (begin (update (car vars) (car vals) env)
                                 (extend (cdr vars) (cdr vals) env))))
        ((null? vars) (if (not (null? vals))
                          (error "More values than symbols to bind with")
                          env))))

;; Helper macros for initializing the global env bind map
```

Problematic code:

```
;; ------------PROBLEM IN THESE MACROS------------------

(define-syntax _def-initial
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_def-initial name)
     (update 'name 'void genv))
    ((_def-initial name value)
     (update 'name value genv))))

(define-syntax _def-primitive
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_def-primitive name value arity)
     (_def-initial name (lambda (args)
                          (if (equal? arity (length args))
                              (apply value args)
                              (error "Incorrect arity" (list 'name value))))))))

(define-syntax _fill-global-env
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_fill-global-env)
     (begin
       (println "Filling the environment")
       (_def-primitive + (lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 2)
       (_def-primitive - (lambda (x y) (- x y)) 2)
       (_def-primitive * (lambda (x y) (* x y)) 2)
       (_def-primitive / (lambda (x y) (/ x y)) 2))
    )))


;; Racket and Guile SAY genv IS UNBOUND

(define get-global-environment
  ;; name must be `genv' coz of the above macros
  (let ( (genv #f) )
    (lambda ()
      (if (equal? genv #f) ;; If uninitialized
          (begin (set! genv (make-new-environment '()))
                 (println "Before filling: "genv)
                 (_fill-global-env)
                 (println "After filling: " genv)
                 genv)
          genv))))

;; ------------------- END OF PROBLEMATIC CODE(IT SEEMS) ---------------
```

Continue:

```
;; - Start the interpreter
(define (main args)
  ;; Define the global environment
  (define genv (get-global-environment))
  (println "Global environment: " genv)
  (let loop ((expr (read (current-input-port))))
    (if (eof-object? expr)
        (println "Done")
        (begin (println (evaluate expr genv))
               (loop (read (current-input-port)))))))

(main "")
```

Here's the error I receive from Racket (in problematic code's `get-global-environment`'s body, not in `main`'s body):

```
. . genv: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier
```

Comment: This is the expansion I *seem* to get from (_fill-global-env) http://paste.debian.net/138158/

Comment: Chris has already answered, but I wanted to mention `((_ expr) (begin (display expr) (newline)))` in `println` is redundant since the pattern `(_ expr expr* ...)` matches 1 to n arguments. (`expr* ...` can match zero elements).

Comment: @Sylwester Indeed, and because it comes after the 1+ case, it won't even fire at all, ever.

Comment: @Sylwester oh I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheme macros are [*hygienic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro). The `genv` you defined in `get-global-environment` is not the same as the `genv` in your `_def-initial` (which uses whatever `genv` was there when `_def-initial` was defined, which in this case would be the top-level one, which as you pointed out does not exist).

In order to make your macro work, you must adapt `_fill-global-env`, `_def-primitive`, and `_def-initial` to all take a `genv` parameter, so that `_def-initial` uses *that* `genv` instead of the top-level one.

Comment: Aaah, I see. Thanks a lot, I still have a lot more to learn about scheme's macros it seems. (The book has the global env variable at top level, I was trying to keep it in the main procedure, just because. :|) I accept your answer.